# What is the distribution of sum of dependent normal random variables?

Tags: probability, statistics

If $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are **dependent** normal random variables, what would be the distribution of $X_1+\ldots+Xn$?
Is it still normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how they are dependent.

The answer is yes if they are [multivariate normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution) but [not always in general](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent#An_asymmetric_example).

Comment: @May: if they are independent (as in the first *i* of *iid*) then $\sum_i \sum_j X_i Y_j =  \sum_i X_i  \times \sum_j Y_j $.  So if they are normally distributed then you have the product of two normal random variables, which is in general [not normally distributed](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalProductDistribution.html)